# Impossible to join AD DS domain, nslookup don't find the domain, but the IP pings

Tags: windows-10

All is here:
[image: all is here]

and here:
[image: and here]

Why can't I join the AD DS domain from "Windows 10" and why can't I resolve the name mathieu.local?

Comment: Did you _tell_ your LAN DNS server how to resolve the name "mathieu.local"?

Comment: How to do it ? I added the IP of the server as the DNS of the client windows 10 and does not work

Comment: Did you add it as the _only_ DNS server, or as an additional server alongside the existing LAN one? What software does the existing LAN DNS server run?

Comment: Yes as the only one, does not work at all

Comment: Even though the `nslookup` fails, can you `ping mathieu.local`? The reason I'm asking is that `.local` domains are not in DNS (or at least the definitely [should not be in DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)) but instead represent non-manged domains. If this is the name of the domain then going forward it _will_ cause more and more problems like this

Comment: ping mat.local does not work

Comment: @user1796465 can you do `nslookup mathieu.local 192.168.1.24`? That should at least tell you if DNS is working. If not working, could be firewall on the DC. If it does work, then can you add a screenshot of the IP/DNS settings on the Win10 vm?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably find a much better audience in the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.